# Redefinition with typedef: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a vector class (where I am recreating the std::vector) and at the very beginning of it I am using typedef to redefine some names. In particular, I have these four lines of code:

```
typedef RAIterator<pointer>                                     iterator;
typedef RAIterator<const_pointer>                               const_iterator;
typedef reverse_iterator<iterator>                              reverse_iterator;
typedef reverse_iterator<const_iterator>                        const_reverse_iterator;
```

`reverse_iterator` and `RAIterator` are other classes I have already implemented. The fourth line of code generates the following error:

```
error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
                typedef reverse_iterator<const_iterator>                                                const_reverse_iterator;
```

If I comment the fourth line, everything works smoothly. Why is this happening?

Comment: fwiw, for a vector you can use pointers as iterators

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
```

Read that very carefully: you're trying to introduce the type name `reverse_iterator`, but that name already exists: the `reverse_iterator` templated class

If you want to have the template `reverse_iterator<>` be actually a `reverse_iterator<iterator>`, you should instead resort to default template arguments.

Comment: also, this is a matter of taste, but unless your compiler is so old that you *really* need to update it, I find `using iterator = RAIterator<pointer>;` to be the easier-to-read alternative to `typedef`.